# Iterating numbers within a string (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, output, printf, storage

In Matlab I am trying to achieve the following:

I need to provide an end date, which I would like to iterate forward by quarter in the format:
'1970q1'
For this I have made a loop.

```
for yy=1970:1971
    for jj=1:4
        fprintf('''%dq%d''',(yy),(jj))        
    end
end
```

However, when I set enddate=fprintf

```
for yy=1970:1971
    for jj=1:4
        enddate=fprintf('''%dq%d''',(yy),(jj))        
    end
end
```

within the loop, it does not store the end date as what the fprintf output is, but something else. The way the end date should be stored is:
enddate='1970q1'

Comment: enddate = sprintf('%dq%d', yy, jj);

Comment: You meant to use `sprintf`, not `fprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sprintf` function for creating strings instead of `fprintf` that writes text to file.

In your case, if you want to save all the enddate values you should save it in a vector:

```
enddate = [];
for yy=1970:1971
    for jj=1:4
        enddate=[enddate sprintf('''%dq%d''',(yy),(jj))];      
    end
end
```